# Define port to read GPS data from in python gps.py library

Tags: python

I have the following code to read GPS data from gps module on raspberry pi. I do not understand how to define from which port the data is read from (For example, using serial library it would be done by doing `serial.Serial(SERIAL_PORT, baudrate = 9600, timeout = 0.5)`.
So my question is: how do i define which port gps module is connected to by using gps.py library
Edit: module is connected via usb.

```
from gps import *
import time

running = True

def getPositionData():
    nx = gpsd.next()
    if nx['class'] == 'TPV':
        latitude = getattr(nx,'lat', "Unknown")
        longitude = getattr(nx,'lon', "Unknown")
        print("Your position: lon = " + str(longitude) + ", lat = " + str(latitude))

gpsd = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE|WATCH_NEWSTYLE)

try:
    print ("Application started!")
    while running:
        getPositionData(gpsd)
        time.sleep(1.0)

except (KeyboardInterrupt):
    running = False
    print ("Applications closed!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using gpsd to receive the data from the GPS device, the configuration of the serial port is set when the GPS Daemon is started.

The following tutorial explains how to configure gpsd

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps-on-the-raspberry-pi/setting-everything-up

The following line sets the serial port

```
sudo gpsd /dev/ttyUSB0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
```